# How to drop Ith row of a data frame

Tags: python

How do I drop row number i of a DF ?

I did the thing below but it is not working.

```
 DF = DF.drop(i)
```

So I wonder what I miss there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass a **label** to [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html). Here `drop` tries to use `i` as a label and fails (ith `KeyError`) as your index probably has other values. Worse, if the index was composed of integers in random order you might drop an incorrect row without noticing it.

Use:

```
df.drop(df.index[i])
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(4)}, index=list('ABCD'))
out = df.drop(df.index[2])
```

output:

```
   col
A    0
B    1
D    3
```

##### pitfall

In case of duplicated indices, you might remove unwanted rows!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(4)}, index=list('ABAD'))
out = df.drop(df.index[2])
```

output (`A` is incorrectly dropped!):

```
   col
B    1
D    3
```

##### workaround:

```
import numpy as np

out = df[np.arange(len(df)) != i]
```

drop several indices by position:

```
import numpy as np

out = df[~np.isin(np.arange(len(df)), [i, j])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add square brackets:

```
df = df.drop([i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```py
df.drop(df.index[i])
```